# How to move VSCode installation without losing extensions and settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have an empty SSD and I want to move VSCode from my HDD to the SSD, but I don't want to lose my extensions and settings.

Answer (score 0):

Just login/signup to your account right from VS Code and keep your extensions attached to your account

[image]